# Ensuring the same DbContext within a SCOPED Request

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework (EF) Core, SCOPED OBJECTS are the same within a request (but different across different requests).  Calling AddDbContext is supposed to be SCOPED by-default...so I am expecting each DbContext instance to be the same instance when marked as SCOPED...and it's not.

I know this because every DbContext handed-up using Dependency Injection (DI) has a different ContextId...and "save changes" no longer works across all Repository's in my UnitOfWork.  As such, it seems like DbContext creation is acting TRANSIENT not SCOPED.

Q: How do I guarantee each instance of the concrete DbContext is the same object in EF Core's DI-model?

Why do I want this?
Calling the UnitOfWork's "save changes" used to work across all Repository's...but not anymore because each DbContxet is different (and has a separate change tracker)

Lamar Service Registry Code:

```
public class ContainerRegistry : ServiceRegistry
{
    public ContainerRegistry()
    {
        Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            scan.LookForRegistries();
            scan.SingleImplementationsOfInterface();
        });

        // --------
        // DATABASE
        //ForSingletonOf<WorkflowComponentDbContext>(); //<-- Doesnt work b/c each DbContext is still a separate instance

        For<DbContext>().Use<WorkflowComponentDbContext>();
        For(typeof(IAuditableRepository<>)).Use(typeof(GenericAuditableRepository<>));

        // Policies (are used to map Constructor args)
        Policies.Add<GenericRepositoryConfiguredInstancePolicy>();
        Policies.Add<UnitOfWorkConfiguredInstancePolicy>();
    }
}
```

Host Builder Code:

```
private IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder()
                        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                        {
                            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                        })
                        .UseServiceProviderFactory<ServiceRegistry>(new LamarServiceProviderFactory())
                        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                        {
                            var connectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString(JsonSettings.ConnectionStrings.WorkflowComponentDb);
                            
                            services.AddLamar(IoC.Build());
                            services.AddScoped<IWindowsIdentityHelper, WindowsIdentityHelper>();
                            
                            // This is supposedly SCOPED by-default?
                            // And while, this passes-back OPTIONS correctly...it isn't passing a "singleton object" throughout the request
                            services.AddDbContext<ProjectManagementDbContext>((provider, options) => 
                            {
                                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                            });
                            services.AddDbContext<WorkflowComponentDbContext>((provider, options) =>
                            {
                                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                            });
                            
                            // This doesnt work either b/c it hands-back a new instacne of the Factoty each time (I tested this)....
                            //services.AddDbContextFactory<WorkflowComponentDbContext, WorkflowComponentDbContextFactory>((provider, options) =>
                            //{
                            //  options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                            //}, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
                        });
    return builder;
}
```

LOW-TECH OPTION: Pass-in the IContainer
I really don't want to do this...but can

```
// -----
// NOTE: Some code omitted for brevity
public class WorkflowComponentUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    // OPTION: I could pass the IContainer to build some dependecies?
    public WorkflowComponentUnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext, IContainer container)
    {
        DbContext = dbContext;

        ContextType = new GenericAuditableRepository<ContextType>(DbContext);
        ContextType.AuditResolver = container.GetRequiredService<IAuditResolverOf<ContextType>>();

        ObjectState = new GenericAuditableRepository<ObjectState>(DbContext);
        ObjectState.AuditResolver = container.GetRequiredService<IAuditResolverOf<ObjectState>>();

        ObjectStateEvent = new GenericAuditableRepository<ObjectStateEvent>(DbContext);
        ObjectStateEvent.AuditResolver = container.GetRequiredService<IAuditResolverOf<ObjectStateEvent>>();

        Workflow = new GenericAuditableRepository<Workflow>(DbContext);
        Workflow.AuditResolver = container.GetRequiredService<IAuditResolverOf<Workflow>>();

        WorkflowEvent = new GenericAuditableRepository<WorkflowEvent>(DbContext);
        WorkflowEvent.AuditResolver = container.GetRequiredService<IAuditResolverOf<WorkflowEvent>>();

        WorkflowTransition = new GenericAuditableRepository<WorkflowTransition>(DbContext);
        WorkflowTransition.AuditResolver = container.GetRequiredService<IAuditResolverOf<WorkflowTransition>>();
    }

    public virtual void SubmitChanges()
    {
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

LOW-TECH OPTION: Call "save changes" across all repository's
I really don't want to do this...but can

```
// -----
// NOTE: Some code omitted for brevity
public class WorkflowComponentUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    [SetterProperty]
    public IAuditableRepository<ContextType> ContextType { get; set; }

    [SetterProperty]
    public IAuditableRepository<ObjectState> ObjectState { get; set; }

    [SetterProperty]
    public IAuditableRepository<ObjectStateEvent> ObjectStateEvent { get; set; }

    [SetterProperty]
    public IAuditableRepository<Workflow> Workflow { get; set; }

    [SetterProperty]
    public IAuditableRepository<WorkflowEvent> WorkflowEvent { get; set; }
    
    [SetterProperty]
    public IAuditableRepository<WorkflowTransition> WorkflowTransition { get; set; }

    // OPTION: I could call "Save Changes" across each Repository
    public virtual void SubmitChanges()
    {
        ContextType.SaveChanges();
        ObjectState.SaveChanges();
        ObjectStateEvent.SaveChanges();
        Workflow.SaveChanges();
        WorkflowEvent.SaveChanges();
        WorkflowTransition.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

UPDATES:
Using the following does not work...

```
For<DbContext>().Use<WorkflowComponentDbContext>().Scoped();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to your question: The documentation here (https://jasperfx.github.io/lamar/guide/ioc/lifetime.html) adds an extra `.Scoped()` to the `For<I>().Use<T>().`. Looks like you should add this to your Lamar-definition of `ProjectManagementDbContext`.

Additionally: Why do you use `services.AddDbContext<ProjectManagementDbContext>(..)` **and** `For<DbContext>().Use<ProjectManagementDbContext>()`. There is an overload for `AddDbContext<T1, T2>(..)`.

As an advice (from my own error): The way you have to setup your DI would mean, that **all** DbContexts share state. Consider refactoring your code to be able use transient DbContexts (from the names given maybe your repositories are just wrapping `DbSet`s ... but that's just a guess).

Comment: RE: "Services.AddDbContext & For<DbContext>":  This application takes-in multiple UnitOfWork's.  Meaning, it talks to 2 separate databases.  That said...the "For<DbContext>" piece tells Lamar maps which concrete to plug for DbContext.  Meanwhile..."Services.AddDbContext" is used to gather DbContextOptions and set Host Scope.

Comment: RE:  "All DbContexts share state": Yes, that is correct...all Repositiry's should use the same DbContext instance.  Otherwise, Change Tracking will only work within 1 Repository at-a-time...and you have to call "Save Changes" across all Repository's manually (I have tested this).

Comment: RE: "Services.AddDbContext & For<DbContext>": That said...If you have a better setup I'm definitely interested in seeing it.  Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Regarding ""For<DbContext>" piece tells Lamar...": You can do that as well with the mentioned overload of AddDbContext. Just use `AddDbContext<DbContext, ProjectManagementDbContext>`. No need to configure things in two places.  
Regarding "if you have a better setup": that would need more insight to your requirements. But generally speaking having just one system being responsible for DI to me seems better. Why do you need both?

Comment: RE: "Why do you need both": This is my 1st SWAG at Core DI & I would LOVE to be able to configure as much as possible in Lamar (and simply consume THAT).  However, I have not been successful setting DbContextOptions in Lamar (I figured it was because the "proper values" exist only in the Host).  As such...I've been using Lamar for class definition & Host for SCOPE.

Comment: Please see UPDATES (above).  Thanks for the help

Comment: Does it work, when you remove the Lamar definition and use just the above overload of `AddDbContext`? If so you could configure everything else in Lamar and just use EF DI from MS. Unfortunately I don't know Lamar, so I can't tell, whether it plays well together with the _standard DI_. It might as well be a matter of when to call `services.AddLamar(IoC.Build());` (before the standard definitions as it is now or after all standard definitions have been made).

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  I am going to have to experiment without use of Lamar to figure out where the issue is...I will update you.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code conceptually:

```cs
For<DbContext>().Use<WorkflowComponentDbContext>().Scoped()
```

When StructureMap / Lamar was first created, an HTTP request was processed on a single thread. In those days `Scoped` objects used thread local storage.

C# usage has switched to an async await model since then. So it is possible that you are getting a problem after an await call, when code resumes on a new thread. This might cause a new DbContext to be created. I could be wrong - but worth checking if this is the cause.

If so, you may need to create a custom scope that stores objects against the HTTP request. I ran into this a while back with Spring Boot, and had to write [this custom scope](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/dependencies/CustomRequestScope.java).

Comment: I tried this prior & it didn't work.  How is this different from the previous answer above?  Am I missing something?